# Rotating a UIView before animation happens

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I'd like to rotate an instance of my UIView subclass before scaling it with an animation. Unfortunately the code I have rotates and scales in the same animation. **How can I complete or force the rotation before any scaling animation happens?**

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(myAngle);

    // other layout...
}

- (void) showMyView {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:something];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:somethingElse];

    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(x, y, z);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is recommended by apple to use the Block syntax for animation stuff.
In addition to that it makes it easier to achieve what you want.

First make the animation for your rotation and if it's done make the scaling stuff.
Code example:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     // This rotates the layer by 90°
                     self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0);
                 }
                 // On completition start the scaling
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                                          animations:^{
                                              // This scales
                                              self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
                                          }
                          ];
                     }
                 }
    ];
```

It is also possible with the "old" animation style you use, but it's more complicated to implement the animation delegate etc...

Comment: Ahh good idea. In the above code can the first animation duration just be zero?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you actually don't need to animate it.
Just append your rotation to your view and start the second animation afterwards.